# How to compare an old GET variable against a new GET variable?

Tags: php, web-applications

I'm working on a PHP application where users can filter search results based on 4 different categories. Switching a category affects the **GET** variable `page_type`.

In my case, the fields for each category need to stay the same while navigating pages (*they are stored in session variables*), however if `page_type` changes, then the session variables need to be unset so that the user doesn't need to spend time deleting all the old data from the last category.

Can someone help me figure out a way to compare an old **GET** variable against a new one? If this is not possible, then is there an efficient way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: You can have multiple URL query variables and you should generate the anchor src values automatically to include the current state. In other words, you don't need to store anything in the session, and you should also avoid the session for such storage needs.

Comment: Definitely not any way to get an old GET value unless you store it somewhere (presumably in the session).

Comment: You say that you already store this in session, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Keep the `page_type` in the session as well, and check against it on every page. If it's different, unset the session and do whatever you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You must past all the info necessary for the search in the page-nav links (all the 'fields' for the category).  If you store the data in a session like you are doing then the BACK button won't work correctly. (Hitting back will return to the page but the fields stored in the session variables would have changed).

Alternatively - you could use a keyed array to store your fields in the session, this way the session variables would be stored separately based on the field_type

```
$_SESSION['search_fields'][$_GET['page_type']] = $fields_array
```

Again, you shouldn't use $_SESSIONS for this because you are eating up server resources creating sessions for users who hit the page through google (or other external link) and never go anywhere else.  Besides, a good search engine should give the user what they want on the first page anyway :-)

Comment: Is using **$_SESSIONS** going to be detrimental to the server if there are probably only a few users (probably 10 max) at a time using the application? It's for faculty administrators only, so it's not public by any means. From the previous comments, I'm considering just passing this information using **$_GET** because it sounds like it would be easier.